# How to fix : ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0 (from versions: none)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently having an issue with the installation of the Tensorflow GPU on mac os

I have uninstalled tensorflow 1.14 and trying to install tensorflow 1.14 GPU in order to train a model.

```
(deepspeech-venv) Chabanis-MacBook-Pro:Deepspeech chabani$ pip3 install 'tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0'
Collecting tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
```

I expected that this would have installed the Tensorflow GPU 1.14 properly. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) there is no GPU support on mac

> macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) or later (64-bit) (**no GPU support**)

No GPU support on Mac is mentioned also [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source)

> There is no GPU support for macOS.